# How do molecular recognition features work?

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins

The occurrence of relatively short (10–70 residues), loosely structured protein regions bind within longer, largely disordered sequences that were characterized as bound to larger proteins. These regions are MoRFs. But how do these high specificity regions combined with low affinity proteins?